# React - dynamically loaded images not showing up in server side rendering

Tags: reactjs, express, create-react-app, server-side-rendering

I'm loading various images in my site like this:

```
  render () {
    const imageUrl = require(`assets/images/${this.props.image}`)
    return (
      <img 
        className={this.props.className} 
        src={imageUrl} 
        alt={this.props.description} 
        itemProp={this.props.itemprop} />
    )
  }
```

When using `yarn start` to view my client-side code only, this is working fine. However, in server-side rendering, my images all have `src="[object Object]"`. I'm further surprised that the images aren't being 'hydrated' once the client-side code downloads from the server.

How can I properly load my image `src` attributes dynamically using server-side rendering?

Comment: How about `const imageUrl = React.lazy(()=>import(assets/images/${this.props.image}))`  and then wrapp `img` with `Suspense`

Comment: @Amir-Mousavi it might make the images appear, but in server-side rendering I don't want to lazy load anything - I want everything to be statically rendered via the server.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know exactly *why* the impact of this was a src of `[Object object]` for my dynamically imported images, but the issue was my build directory was not correctly referenced in my Express app doing the server rendering.

Changing:

```
app.use(express.static('/../build')))
```

to:

```
app.use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '../build')))
```

solved the issue.